# Stream video to TV

Tags: c#, video, stream, television

I would like to stream videos from my computer to a television, just like WMP does it and I'd prefer to use `libvlc` if thats possible, as I'm using it anyway in my application. I did a lot of search, but I can hardly find anything and I don't know where to start.

Thanks for any help on that.

PS: I want the video to start on the tv right away, like when you use Windows Media Player to stream, not like a media server or something, where I have to choose the media at the tv.

Comment: Lets just spend all our quality time on some arb question on stackoverflow which OP has no idea on

Comment: I just want to know where to start, and if it's possible using libvlc.

Comment: Do you mean [PlayTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465183.aspx)?

Comment: Yes something like that, thanks. But I would really like to use the vlc codecs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use DLNA or UPnP:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/andrea-upnp/files/ Andrea UPnP Suite

UPnP API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382303.aspx

UPnP provide direct TV control from PC such as:send media file to TV, play, pause, stop and others.